# Why doesn't Eloquent\Builder inherit from Query\Builder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, the [Eloquent\Builder](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Builder.html) class sends every call to methods which it doesn't have to an internal [Query\Builder](http://laravel.com/api/4.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html). To me this sounds like inheritance. Somebody knows why they didn't implement it so that the `Eloquent\Builder` extends `Query\Builder`? The reason I first noticed it was that I got "Call to undefined method" errors in IDEs, despite the code working fine which is the curse of magic methods I suppose.

For reference, here is relevant source from `Eloquent\Builder`.

```
/**
 * The base query builder instance.
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
protected $query;

protected $passthru = array(
    'toSql', 'lists', 'insert', 'insertGetId', 'pluck', 'count',
    'min', 'max', 'avg', 'sum', 'exists', 'getBindings',
);

public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (method_exists($this->model, $scope = 'scope'.ucfirst($method)))
    {
        return $this->callScope($scope, $parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        $result = call_user_func_array(array($this->query, $method), $parameters);
    }

    return in_array($method, $this->passthru) ? $result : $this;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to make clear it is a laravel specific question. Updated the question.

Comment: Are you getting some actual errors? Or just IDE notices?

Comment: Just notices. However I'm not concerned with them, the question is about why `Eloquent\Builder` doesn't extend `Query\Builder`.

Comment: Why is it even important for you?

Comment: Smart people coded in a way I didn't understand. Felt like a good enough reason to ask about it. Plus, I was annoyed by the warnings and lack of auto-complete so I hoped they had a good reason for taking that path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start off with my conclusion.  I think it was just poorly engineered.

Let me do a few explanations, and also reply to the accepted answer by @Simon Bengtsson

I'm by no means trying to offend anyone, but I'm just trying to word out my thoughts.

---

Actually the whole point of inheritance is that they have similar characteristics, but you would like to add an extra layer to put some extended features.  Obviously, the extended "child" class will know more than the "parent" class (such as knowing about the Eloquent Model)

To me, a "Builder" is a Builder.  Afterall, both are actually building a query, regardless of what conditions its checking or observing.  That's the purpose of a Builder (from what I see at least).  So it's in the same layer (except `Eloquent\Builder` has some extra features).

The current implementation is overriding the nature of a few methods such as where() (which are basically those in `Query\Builder`, same name, same arguments).  It's also adding a few methods, which eventually calls methods like where().  This is all about inheritance.  If I call where(), and it exists in child class, the child class method gets called.  If not, it will call the method in parent class.

---

> Later down the line it becomes more difficult to then decouple the low level and ORM level components if you hypothetically wanted to use some new NoSQL DB instead 
>   and simply write a Query\Builder signature compliant drop-in class.

@Simon Bengtsson

I don't see how it gets difficult to decouple.  All you have to do, is to write a new class `Query\MongoDBBuilder`, which has the same interface as `Query\Builder`.  If you're worried, you can always make the classes "implements" an Interface.  If you ask me, actually the current way is harder to decouple, because it's quite messy right now as to "which features are overridden and which are not".

I do encourage class decoupling in some cases, but if I were to decouple this one (which I don't think is necessary here), I would do it this way:

- `Eloquent\Model`
- `Eloquent\Adapter` (This is some sort of intermediate layer, where you could put connection settings etc.)
- `Eloquent\Builder extends Query\Builder` (This is a "wrapper" for Query\Builder so that it could do slightly more, but achieving the same goals)

---

> Child classes also have access to protected properties on parent classes so that Eloquent\ChildOfQueryBuilder would have the freedom to rely on the low level implementation 
>   of Query\Builder and could be coupled to it.

@Simon Bengtsson

This is the whole point about inheritance.  You would to be able to access protected properties to override a feature given by the parent.  Let's look at it from another point of view, what if you NEED to access these variables in order to modify the feature?  In fact, the author declaring these members "protected" already implies that he is ready for another class to extend it.  That's the only purpose of making it "protected", correct?

That's why you would have to know exactly what a parent class is doing before inheriting it, because it could be dangerous.

---

The reason why I'm giving this huge explanation is because I'm trying to modify some features for Eloquent.  I've been looking at the implementation of days (the 3 god classes: `Eloquent\Model`, `Eloquent\Builder`, and `Query\Builder`).  The layering and aliasing was really messed up.  Extending the `Model` class requires me to redeclare almost equivalent functions due to its poor implementation.  But that's off topic.

In conclusion, if you ask "why", I would actually say (now I know people will kick me) that it was just poorly engineered and implemented.

Answer (score 4):

I think [delmadord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25163011/1852838) was sort of heading towards the right answer but I think bringing the IoC into it blurs the issue. The basic answer is that the two classes represent abstractions of the database at different levels. `Query\Builder` is the lower level abstraction and `Eloquent\Builder` is a higher level abstraction which is why, as you pointed out it makes use of `Query\Builder` for its core functionality.

You can tell this from the properties that are defined for each class. One has properties surrounding things such as:

- connection settings,
- database grammars and,
- various things relating to the query that will be assembled

The other is more an ORM and is concerned with higher level concerns such as whether eager relationship loading should be used and which model the query is currently bound to. Arguably, you could use inheritance here and might have pretty much the same functionality but from an architectural standpoint there are issues with this.

One is that, strictly speaking, I should always be able to use a **child** class as a drop in replacement for a **parent** class. This is simpler to see if you adopt the "***is a***" reading of inheritance. This means that if you used inheritance for this pair of classes, strictly speaking, any developer down the line is able to make use of `Eloquent\Builder` just as easily as `Query\Builder` and in fact might be encouraged to do so throughout the code in order to have one less class to track in their minds. This will mean code may call `$builder->getRelation()` and rely on the consequences on (for argument's sake) `$builder->wheres` all in the same block of code.

Later down the line it becomes more difficult to then decouple the low level and ORM level components if you hypothetically wanted to use some new NoSQL DB instead and simply write a `Query\Builder` signature compliant drop-in class.

Child classes also have access to **protected** properties on parent classes so that `Eloquent\ChildOfQueryBuilder` would have the freedom to rely on the low level implementation of `Query\Builder` and could be coupled to it. You could argue that you could just make it **private** but then you can  longer write a thin low-level extension to `Query\Builder` (adding some clustering, sharding or security logic maybe) that may (rightfully) need access to the implementation details that could have been a drop-in replacement for the low-level functionality.

Another is that the size of the class grows quite rapidly if you pile everything related into one "[God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)". Both of the `Builder` classes have a large amount of abstraction layer specific logic within them. If you inherit, then `Eloquent\Builder` would effectively be the union of the two and you would have almost twice as much code to scan for issues and your IDE would give you a much broader range of autocompletion options, with a significant fraction being unrelated to the abstraction depth you're working at.

---

The same pattern is used sometimes in other places where two classes are very related to each other, but inheritance would cause perception issues which would encourage their use in ways the developer does not want. With Java for example, *immutable* classes typically have *mutable* counterparts but neither inherits the other and they might not even have common ancestry.

This happens because the *immutable* class can't have any *mutator* methods. Inheriting from the *mutable* version would require overriding and disabling each *mutator* method and forever ensuring this happens correctly. Forget this once and your *immutable* class may be *mutable* for a few revisions. And you can't allow inheritance the other way around because doing so means a method expecting an *immutable* class might get a *mutable* **child** and add grey hairs to people.

This is another instance of related things playing distinct roles and thus being conceptually separated. Its not that you can't do things a particular way but more that certain architecture choices discourage behaviours you don't want and leave room to do things that you do think you'll want to do down the line. Sometimes with very large code-bases, decoupling things along an interface like that really helps to make it easier to reason about and work with.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the source of [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php)

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;

class Builder {

    /**
     * The base query builder instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
     */
    protected $query;
```

You can see, that it is using the **instance** of the [Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php). It is not *extending* the class, probably for make use of the [IoC](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc) in Laravel. Inject the instance and it get pulled everything needed.

Comment: I have read the source and the whole question is about why Eloquent\Builder doesn't extend Query\Builder.

Comment: As I have wrote there, it is because of Laravel is making use of the IoC dependency injecting.

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question. We can see it uses a Query\Builder instance within the class, the question was _why_ this was chosen vs inheriting it. The fact that the Eloquent\Builder uses a __call magic method that calls the base query instance makes no sense to me.